# How does SLSQP iterations work starting from a Sobol Sequence?

Tags: optimization, scipy, scipy-optimize

I have an optimization problem where the initial dataset is filled with samples generated by a Sobol sequence. The optimization algorithm I chose is the SLSQP available in SciPy.

I do understand how SLSQP works in a simple 2D dataset, and I do have an idea about the constraint optimization flow.

However, I do not understand how exactly SLSQP minimizes the error over the whole hypercube, assuming I have a dozen of input parameters and a couple of constraints and a couple of targets. Is there some sort of dimensionality reduction ? If yes, how ?!

Also, how does the SLSQP generate (or focus) on a subset of the hypercube if I have subsequent iterations?

References to books or papers is greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: The algorithm is documented in Kraft, Dieter. "A software package for sequential quadratic programming." Forschungsbericht- Deutsche Forschungs- und Versuchsanstalt fur Luft- und Raumfahrt (1988)

Comment: "However, I do not understand how exactly SLSQP minimizes the error over the whole hypercube" It doesn't. SLSQP is not a global optimizer. A global optimizer is something like [DIRECT](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.direct.html).